# Convert a trigger to a class to clean up the code

Tags: apex, trigger, class

Currently I have a class that that adds credit lines to a credit request object.  I also have a trigger that updates the credit request based on the credit lines.  Since my class adds credit lines, I am curious if the trigger could be incorporated into the class as its own list.  Below is the class and the trigger.  We have limited bandwidth for these items and wanted to see if there is support for on how to accomplish this.

Class

```
public class AddOrUpdateCreditLineTriggerHandler {

    Map<Id, List<Credit_lines__c>> mapCRToCL = new Map<id, List<credit_lines__c>>();
    map<id, Credit_Request__c> original;
    map<id, Credit_Request__c> modified;
    List<Credit_Lines__c> associatedCreditLines;
    List<Credit_lines__c> toDelete = new List<Credit_Lines__c>();
    List<Credit_lines__c> toInsert = new List<Credit_lines__c>();


    public AddOrUpdateCreditLineTriggerHandler(List<Credit_Request__c> original, List<Credit_Request__c> modified) {
        if (original != null) {
            this.original = New Map<Id, Credit_Request__C>(original);
        }
        this.modified = New Map<Id, Credit_Request__c>(modified);
        system.debug('#### - modified: ' + modified);
        associatedCreditLines = [
            SELECT id, Product__C, Name, credit_request__c
            FROM Credit_Lines__C
            WHERE Credit_request__c in :modified
        ];
        for (Credit_lines__c cl: associatedCreditLines) {
            if (mapCRToCL.containsKey(cl.credit_request__c)) {
                mapCRToCL.get(cl.credit_request__c).add(cl);
            } else {
                mapCRToCL.put(cl.credit_request__c, new List<Credit_Lines__c>{
                    cl
                });
            }
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        if (Trigger.isInsert) {
            afterInsert();
        } else if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
            afterUpdate();
        }
    }

    private void afterInsert() {
        for (Credit_Request__c cr : this.modified.values()) {
            toInsert.addAll(createStandardCreditLines(cr));
        }
        insert toInsert;
    }

    private void afterUpdate() {
        for (Credit_Request__c cr : filterQtyChanged(this.modified.values())) {
            if (mapCRToCl.get(cr.id) != null)
                toDelete.addAll(mapCRToCl.get(cr.id));
            delete toDelete;

            toInsert.addAll(createStandardCreditLines(cr));
        }
        insert toInsert;
    }

    private List<Credit_lines__c> createStandardCreditLines(Credit_Request__c cr) {
        List<Credit_Lines__c> created = new List<Credit_Lines__c>();
        for (AutomatedCreditLineRecords__c a: creditLines()) {

            if (cr.RS_Cell_Qty__c == null && cr.Sequel_Cell_Qty__c == null) {
                break;
            }


            Double multiplier = 1;
            if (a.multiplierField__c != null && cr.get(a.multiplierField__c) != null) {
                multiplier = (Double) cr.get(a.multiplierField__c);
            }
            if (a.ProductType__c == 'Sequel' && cr.Sequel_Cell_Qty__c != null)
                created.add(
                    New Credit_lines__c(
                        Credit_Request__c = cr.Id,
                        Quantity__c = (a.Qty__c * multiplier),
                        Product__c = a.productId__c
                    )
                ); else {
            }
            if (a.ProductType__c == 'RS' && cr.RS_Cell_Qty__c != null)
                created.add(
                    New Credit_lines__c(
                        Credit_Request__c = cr.Id,
                        Quantity__c = (a.Qty__c * multiplier),
                        Product__c = a.productId__c
                    )
                );
        }
        return created;
    }


    private List<AutomatedCreditLineRecords__c> CreditLines() {
        return AutomatedCreditLineRecords__c.getall().values();
    }

    private List<Credit_Request__c> filterQtyChanged(List<Credit_Request__c> possible) {
        List<Credit_request__c> toUpdate = new List<Credit_Request__c>();
        for (Credit_Request__c cr : this.modified.values()) {
            if (QuantityChanged(this.original.get(cr.id), cr)) {
                toUpdate.add(cr);
            }
        }
        return toUpdate;
    }

    // Helper methods
    private Boolean QuantityChanged(Credit_Request__c original, Credit_Request__c modified) {
        return (original.RS_cell_qty__c != modified.RS_Cell_Qty__c) ||
            (original.SEQUEL_cell_qty__c != modified.Sequel_cell_qty__c);
    }

}
```

And the trigger to update credit request based on credit lines

```
trigger MakingApprovalRequiredTrigger on Credit_Lines__c (After Insert, After Update, After Delete){

      List<Id> parentIds = new List<Id>();

    If(Trigger.IsInsert || Trigger.IsUpdate){
        For(Credit_Lines__c crdLine : Trigger.New){
            If(crdLine.Credit_Request__c != Null){
                parentIds.add(crdLine.Credit_Request__c);
            }
        }
    }


    If(Trigger.IsDelete){
        For(Credit_Lines__c crdLine : Trigger.Old){
            If(crdLine.Credit_Request__c != Null){
                parentIds.add(crdLine.Credit_Request__c);
            }
        }
    }

    List<Credit_Request__c> parentFinalList = New List<Credit_Request__c>();
    Double d = 0.00;

    For(Credit_Request__c crdReq : [Select Id, Approval_Required__c,Reason_for_request__c,
                                            (Select Id, Quantity__c, Product__c FROM Credit_Lines__r WHERE Product__c = '01t70000004Oxl4AAC' OR Product__c = '01t3900000OMrYrAAL') 
                                                                        FROM Credit_Request__c 
                                                                                WHERE Id =: parentIds])
    {
        d = 0.00;
        Set<String> ProductCodes = New Set<String>();

        For(Credit_Lines__c EveryChild : crdReq.Credit_Lines__r )
        {
            d += EveryChild.Quantity__c;
            ProductCodes.add(String.valueOf(EveryChild.Product__c));
        }
         If(crdReq.Reason_for_request__c.Contains('308 CR-Service/Troubleshooting') || crdReq.Reason_for_request__c.Contains('208 PB-Service/Troubleshooting'))

                If(d > 1.0 && ProductCodes.Contains('01t70000004Oxl4AAC'))
                    {
                        crdReq.Approval_Required__c = true;
                        parentFinalList.add(crdReq );
                    }
                else If(d > 1.0 && ProductCodes.Contains('01t3900000OMrYrAAL'))
                    {
                        crdreq.Approval_Required__c = true;
                        parentFinalList.add(crdReq );
                    }
                else
                    {
                        crdreq.Approval_Required__c = false;
                        parentFinalList.add(crdReq );                
                    }

        else 
            {
                If(d >= 0.5 && ProductCodes.Contains('01t70000004Oxl4AAC'))
                    {
                        crdReq.Approval_Required__c = true;
                        parentFinalList.add(crdReq );
                    }
                else If(d >= 0.0 && ProductCodes.Contains('01t3900000OMrYrAAL'))
                    {
                        crdreq.Approval_Required__c = true;
                        parentFinalList.add(crdReq );
                    }
                else
                    {
                        crdreq.Approval_Required__c = false;
                        parentFinalList.add(crdReq );                
                    }         
            }        


        try
        {
            If(!parentFinalList.IsEmpty()){
                update parentFinalList;
            }
        }
        Catch(Exception e){
            System.debug('Exception Thrown For MakingApprovalRequired Is:: ' + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This sort of request doesn't tend to be a great fit here. The question as written  reads like a request for the community to do your work for you. If you have limited bandwidth and don't have the time to spend on learning the skills you need here, hiring a consultant who is paid for this sort of work may be a better route.

Comment: For future reference, to format an entire section of code as a code block, you can simply highlight the entire block, and press ctrl + k. This ensures that every line has at least 4 spaces at the beginning (and that there's one blank line between your code and any other text). If you don't do this, the first and last lines of code (typically) don't get formatted. If you only add spaces to the first line(s), it'll throw off the indentation (making it harder to read).